# Explicación de este bucle para obtener numeros primos

Tags: javascript

Este código haya los numeros primos que se encuentran del 2 hasta `limit`

```js
function sieve(limit) {
 
  var bools = [];
  var primes = [];

  // generate a list of booleans all set to true initially
  // the array is indexed from 2 to limit representing all numbers
  // e.g. [true, true, true, true] = [2, 3, 4, 5]
  for (var i = 1; i < limit; i++) { bools.push(true); } 

  // loop from 2 to limit setting the composite numbers to false
  // we start from 2 because we know 1 is not a prime number
  for (var i = 2; i < limit; i++) {
    if (bools[i-2]) {
      for (var j = i*2; j <= limit; j += i) {
        bools[j-2] = false;    
      }
    }
  }
  
  // now generate the list of primes only where
  // there is a true value in the bools array
  for (var p = 0; p < bools.length; p++) {
    if (bools[p]) { primes.push(p+2); }
  }
  
 var suma = primes.reduce((x,y) => {return x + y})
 return suma

} 

sieve(30);
```

En este bucle no logro entender que significa ni para que hace `bools[i-2]`

```
 for (var i = 2; i < limit; i++) {
if (bools[i-2]) {
  for (var j = i*2; j <= limit; j += i) {
    bools[j-2] = false;    
  }
}
```

}

Entiendo que se multiplique por dos para saber si es múltiplo, pero porque restarle dos al índice?. Además comprueba si es multiplo de 2 pero no de 3 o de 5 y sin embargo el código funciona.

Comment: Está utilizando la criba de Eratóstenes para marcar los números que no son primos: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criba_de_Erat%C3%B3stenes. Lo del "-2" es por conveniencia: el array `bools` es `[2, 3, 4, ..., limit]`. Los `for` empiezan en `i=2` pero el array empieza en el índice 0.

Comment: Perdona, el array `bools` contiene booleanos, pero como explican arriba `bools[0]` corresponde a `2` (tendrá `true` porque 2 es primo), `bools[1]` corresponde a `3`, y así...